# String replace the contents of a div

Tags: php, jquery, string, replace

## What I want to do:

I have a div with an id. Whenever ">" occurs I want to replace it with ">>". I also want to prefix the div with "You are here: ".

## Example:

```
<div id="bbp-breadcrumb">Home &gt; About &gt; Contact</div>
```

## Context:

My div contains breadcrumb links for bbPress but I'm trying to match its format to a site-wode bread crumb plugin that I'm using for WordPress. The div is called as function in PHP and outputted as HTML.

## My question:

Do I use PHP of Javascript to replace the symbols and how do I go about calling the contents of the div in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS to add the you are here text:

```
#bbp-breadcrumb:before {
    content: "You are here: ";
}
```

Browser support:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html

You could change the > to >> with javascript:

```
var htmlElement = document.getElementById('bbp-breadcrumb');
htmlElement.innerHTML = htmlElement.innerHTML.split('&gt;').join('&gt;&gt;').split('>').join('>>')
```

I don't recommend altering content like this, this is really hacky. You'd better change the ouput rendering of the breadcrumb plugin if possible. Within Wordpress this should be doable.

Comment: the javascript replace function only will work on the first occurrence; try these lines: var text = 'abcbsdbasd'; console.log(text.replace('b', 'd')); you will see that only the first b letter gets replaced

Comment: I avoided the hacky approach as suggested. I used a conditional function (PHP) to change the output: http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/how-do-i-edit-bbpress-breadcrumbs

Answer (score 1):

Find the code that's generating the `&lt;`, and either set the appropriate option (`breadcrumb_separator` or so) or modify the php code to change the separator.

Modifying supposedly static text with JavaScript is not only a maintenance nightmare, extremely brittle, and might lead to a strange rendering (as users see your site being modified if their system is slow), but will also not work in browsers without (or with disabled) JavaScript support.

Comment: Cheers for the advice. I opted to change the output using PHP to change the function that produces the div.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex to match the breadcrumb content.. make the changes on it.. and put it back in the context..
check if this helps you:

```
    $the_existing_html = 'somethis before<div id="bbp-breadcrumb">Home &gt; About &gt; Contact</div>something after'; // let's say this is your curreny html.. just added some context
    echo $the_existing_html, '<hr />'; // output.. so that you can see the difference at the end 
    $pattern ='|<div(.*)bbp-breadcrumb(.*)>(.*)<\/div>|sU'; // find some text that is in a div that has "bbp-breadcrumb" somewhere in its atributes list

    $all = preg_match_all($pattern, $the_existing_html, $matches); // match that pattern

    $current_bc = $matches[3][0]; // get the text inside that div

    $new_bc = 'You are here: ' . str_replace('&gt;', '&gt;&gt;', $current_bc);// replace entity for > with the same thing repeated twice 

    $the_final_html = str_replace($current_bc, $new_bc, $the_existing_html); // replace the initial breadcrumb with the new one 
    echo $the_final_html; // output to see where we got
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the useful PHP code. I instead filtered the function that was outputting the bread crumb content.

Comment: If you're curious you can see how I achieved it here: http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/how-do-i-edit-bbpress-breadcrumbs